# CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language

Tags: android-studio, cmake

I'm trying to build a project in Android Studio and i'm getting this error:

```
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: AAA-jni
```

Since I haven't wrote the code, I tried to find AAA-jni and I found it:

```
"libraries" : 
    {
        "AAA-jni-Release-armeabi-v7a" : 
        {
            "abi" : "armeabi-v7a",
            "artifactName" : "AAA-jni",
            "buildCommand" : "C:\\Users\\Nicky\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\cmake\\3.6.3155560\\bin\\cmake.exe --build C:\\Users\\Nicky\\Documents\\AAAAndroid\\app\\.externalNativeBuild\\cmake\\release\\armeabi-v7a --target AAA-jni",
            "buildType" : "release",
            "output" : "C:/Users/Nicky/Documents/AAAAndroid/app/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/armeabi-v7a/libAAA-jni.so",
            "toolchain" : "3547424389"
        }
    },
```

This is were it gets called in the CMake text file:

```
target_link_libraries( Autour-jni ${log-lib} ${z-lib} )
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you check in the CMakeLists.txt the call to add_executable() if you have one and can you share it? It might be that the sources put there don't have a recognizable extension, so it needs to be modified. Or add_library() if it's a library...

Comment: You can also set the language in `project()` command.

Comment: The linker language is determined by the file extensions of the source files given. Can you please add a `message("sources: ${log-lib} ${z-lib}") to the code and add the output to the question?